# Hiding application source when posting to Facebook fan page via graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've successfully posted to a fan page as the actual page via the Graph API.

The problem is that the post says it was posted at "*time* via *application name*". Is there any way to hide this, so my post looks exactly as if I typed it directly into Facebook?

I'm building a messaging center that can easily deliver messages on many different channels, Facebook being one of them. Clients probably won't appreciate their Facebook posts linking to my application, nor do I want to set up a new Facebook application for each client.

Comment: That would open doors to malicious usage wouldn't it? It is good that you can always see from what application something was posted.

Comment: Sure it would. I was hoping there would be a way for the admin to grant a specific application permission to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to disable this. It is an internal Facebook system and is very deliberate on their part to show users where content comes from and make it easier to report malicious and spammy apps.