# Is it possible with facebook-php-sdk to post to a user's wall without leaving "via" in the status update?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

[My Goal:]

I want to provide users with a facebook login button on my site with a FORM for them to fill out
that will post status updates to their wall from my site so they don't have to leave my site to goto facebook.

[The Situation:]

I'm using the facebook php Software development kit found here:
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

The examples/with_js_sdk.php demo script works for displaying the user's account information.

I have edited it so it posts a new status update to the user's wall with "testing this api' by making the following changes to the script:

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

$facebook->api(
array(
'method' => 'users.setStatus'
, 'status' => 'testing this api'
, 'uid'    => $user_profile['id']
)
);
```

The login button reads:

[My Issue:]
The issue I have with the above is that, unlike a user actually posting to their wall manually, posting via the api includes a link to the api that posted it.
Thus their post on facebook would look like:

is testing this api
4 seconds ago via MyAPINameWithALinkToThePageIDontWantPeopleToKnow

I don't want the API to include the "via" part in the user's status update on their wall.

[My Question:]

Is what I want, as far as leaving out the "via" part in the user's post, possible through the facebook api?

[What I've Tried:]
I've tried looking through the facebook api documentation.
I've tried googling this question and found similar questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756777/remove-app-name-in-app-post-feed-using-facebook-javascript-sdk
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?658541-Facebook-omit-quot-via-app-name-quot-from-Wall-posts
Seems to be hopeless...

Comment: It seems not possible. This looks like a duplicate question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098424/hiding-application-source-when-posting-to-facebook-fan-page-via-graph-api

Answer (score 0):

then I found that this isn't possible via feed dialog. So I used [Open Graph actions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) to accomplish this.

Use this for making your app smart :)